# Unable to get divs sorted properly

Tags: html, css, web

I have been running into some issues with a JS script and have isolated the problems.
My divs are completely messed up.
The layout I am looking for is :

```
wrapper    -    whole page.
        header

left menu 1     right content (stretches to / past left menu item 3)
left menu 2 
left menu 3
      footer
```

I would like the menu items to be contained in a div which is the same height as the right content div.

This is the code I have :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bliss</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling1.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="wholewrap">
<div id="header">header</div>

<div id="middlewrap">

<div id="menuwrap">
<div id="1" class="floatleftnw">1</div>
<div id="1" class="floatleftnw">2</div>
<div id="1" class="floatleftnw">3</div>
</div><!-- end of menu-->

<div id="right" style="float:right; display:inline;">right</div>
</div><!-- end of middlewrap-->
<div id="footer">
footer
</div >

</div><!-- end of whole wrap-->
</body></html>
```

and the css I have (as per styling1.css) is :

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    background:#fff;
}



#wholewrap {
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#right {
    margin-left:220px;
    width:740px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    float:right;
    display:inline;

}

.floatleftnw {
    float:left;
}



#middlewrap {
    height:800px;
    width:1000px;

}


#menuwrap {
    height:800px;
    width:200px;
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid blue;

}

.clearer {
    font-size: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? When I rewrote this layout (last hour or 2) I opened my div and made sure I closed it straight away and even commented it. The code is not showing any errors in DreamWeaver, however when I view in firebug, the divs are not functioning as supposed, I.e the menuwrap should have a blue border around it. Right should be inline with the left menus (I can get the border around the menuwrap, however as soon as I add inline to right's properties, it all gets destroyed.)

Thank you

Comment: use position relative along with float property

Comment: Use tables to position the whole page. That is easier to review.

Comment: look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/MjcMp/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change a bit in ur css as well as in html

#### css

```
#menuwrap {
    background-color: #D3C5C5;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
}
#right {
   height: 100%;
   width: 70%;
   float:left;
   display:block;
   background-color: #fDc3C5;
}

.floatleftnw {
   float:left;
   clear:both;
}
```

#### HTMl ( dont mix inline css and external css )

```
<div id="wholewrap">
<div id="header">header</div>

<div id="middlewrap">

<div id="menuwrap">
<div id="1" class="floatleftnw">1</div>
<div id="1" class="floatleftnw">2</div>
<div id="1" class="floatleftnw">3</div>
</div><!-- end of menu-->

<div id="right">right</div>
</div><!-- end of middlewrap-->
<div id="footer">
footer
</div >

</div><!-- end of whole wrap-->
```

**[`Working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/MjcMp/1/)**

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was after :)

Answer (score 2):

The `inline` property is different from block layout, and will not have block features like border, margin etc. You need to use `display: block` or `display: inline-block` instead.
If you want a vertical menu on the left, you may add `float: left` for `#menuwrap` and remove other floating and `display: inline`. See sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fUexS/)

Answer (score 1):

I have a website with similar structure. My menu on the left side is actually within div section, which is named "left". You should float both your left section and right section to the left as follows:

```
#left {
text-align: left;
width: 180px;
float: left;
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

#right {
text-align: left;
width: 800px;
float: left;
font-size: 10pt;
margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

and the footer should have (clear: both;) in order for it to go beneath left and right.
I am not sure, though, what your "middlewrap" is doing..?

The footer section should be something like this:

```
#footer {
width: 980px;
line-height: 50px;
background-color: #FFF;
clear: both;
color: #000;
border-top: 1px dotted #D1D1D1;
border-bottom: 1px dotted #D1D1D1;
margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info!
My original issue was with a sticky div menu in JS that needed my menu div to be as long as my content div, so I thought if I contained them both in a "middle wrapper" that may do the trick, turns out it has just given me a major headache... lol

Comment: You are welocme, Nik. Happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is right correct. If you want the two divs both Nav and Main content the same height you were just missing a height on #right.

http://jsfiddle.net/MD2KT/1/ This is with the elements blocked and heights specified.